# Fetching objects from database in Symfony 2.7.3

Tags: symfony, oop, orm, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm trying to show some object properties stored on the database. I've got the controller, the Entity, and the view. I'get no excepctions but I can't see the object properties.

Controller:

```
/**
* @Route ("/ov", name="ov")
*/
public function select(){

    $a=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:PC')->find(2);

    if(!$a){
        throw $this->createNotFoundExcepction('No PC');
    }

   return $this->render('PcDetailed.html.twig', array('pcs' => $a));

}
```

View:

```
{% extends 'master.html.twig' %}
{% block divCentral %}
    <div class="row">
        <p>Nom del pc</p>
        <div class="small-6 small-centered columns">
            {% for pc in pcs %}
                <p>{{ pc.nom }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Edit:

Finally, like Chris says, the problem is 'cause on the View I'm using I'm trying to iterate is an object, not an array. That's why doesn't work.

That's the way I must do it:

```
return $this->render('PcDetailed.html.twig', array('pcs' => array($a)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you get the PC with id 2 and pass it to the view.

In the view you are now trying to iterate over this object. I have no idea what TWIG does when you try to iterate over something that is not an array or a collection but maybe it just fails silently.

To fix it, change your controller code to send an array to the view:

```
return $this->render('PcDetailed.html.twig', array('pcs' => array($a)));
```

Comment: You're right, I thought the iteration doesn't affect me. Thank you.